# Are hidden files in /usr/share/man a security concern?

Tags: security, rkhunter

`rkhunter` reported that

```
[17:15:45]   Checking for hidden files and directories       [ Warning ]
[17:15:45] Warning: Hidden file found: /etc/.updated: ASCII text
[17:15:45] Warning: Hidden file found: /usr/share/man/man5/.k5identity.5.gz: gzip compressed data, max compression, from Unix, truncated
[17:15:45] Warning: Hidden file found: /usr/share/man/man5/.k5login.5.gz: gzip compressed data, max compression, from Unix, truncate
```

Looking at the files

```
vorac@msi:/usr/share/man/man5$ ll .k5*
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root 42 Nov 13 20:07 .k5identity.5.gz
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root 39 Nov 13 20:07 .k5login.5.gz

vorac@msi:/usr/share/man/man5$ file .k5*
.k5identity.5.gz: gzip compressed data, max compression, from Unix, truncated
.k5login.5.gz:    gzip compressed data, max compression, from Unix, truncated

vorac@msi:/usr/share/man/man5$ pacman -F .k5*
core/krb5 1.19.2-2 [installed]
    usr/share/man/man5/.k5identity.5.gz
core/krb5 1.19.2-2 [installed]
    usr/share/man/man5/.k5login.5.gz
```

Are those possibly malicious?

Comment: The `.k5login` & `.k5identity` are normal. Try `man .k5login`. `/etc/.updated` is a plain text file from `systemd`, and utterly boring...

Answer (score 1):

The `/etc/.updated` is used by [`systemd-update-done.service`](https://www.freedesktop.org/software/systemd/man/systemd-update-done.service.html) and `/usr/share/man/man5/` by `man` program.

You can use `ALLOWHIDDENFILE=/path/to/hidden/file` in your configuration to disable the rkhinter warning.